# Как можно улучшить данное предложение

Tags: лексика, стилистика, выбор-слов

У меня получился такой перевод:

> Помпа, подключённая к электросети, будет пропускать жидкость, но только в одном направлении.

Скажите пожалуйста, как можно улучшить это предложение?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В русской технической терминологии слово "помпа" (пожарная, корабельная) как разновидность насоса используется редко. Речь идёт о (малом) насосе вообще, безотносительно его устройства, дополнительных возможностей (типа реверса, принципиально возможного для некоторых типов насосов) и пр. Поэтому правильнее "**насос**".
2. Как показывает контекст (https://wiki.factorio.com/Pump), буквальное "**пропускание**" жидкости здесь *верно*, поскольку речь идёт об использовании насоса в качестве управляемого клапана. Далее говорится, что в выключенном состоянии (if unpowered) насос ничего не пропускает. Применять ли в русском варианте буквальное будущее время - вопрос стиля. Да, так пишут для покупателей электровентиляторов (при включении = после него он закрутится или "будет крутиться"). В технических текстах (если речь не идёт об особенностях переходного процесса включения) описывают состояние (здесь включённое состояние powered противопоставляется выключенному un-powered - пропускает/не пропускает). В исходном же варианте просматривается противоречие между обозначенным состоянием (подключённая) и временем (будет).
3. Указание на одно направление переведено не до конца: речь о направлении, которое соответствует ориентации входа и выхода насоса (its set position) относительно двух частей трубы.

Предлагаемый вариант:

> Во включённом состоянии насос пропускает через себя жидкость, но
>   только в направлении, в котором он установлен.

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю, что русский перевод должен **точно передавать содержание источника,** но при этом должны использоваться **обороты и конструкции русского языка.**

Мое предложение звучало именно по-русски: насос качает воду в одном из двух направлений, это направление задается **при его настройке.**

Вы говорите так:  **насос пропускает жидкость**? Насос не должен пропускать жидкость, в исправном состоянии он герметичный. И  что означает "**в направлении, в котором он установлен"**? Вдоль стены или поперек? И как лучше сказать: **при включении или во включенном состоянии?**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1) Оригинал

When powered, the pump will let liquids through, but only in its set direction.

2) Перевод (в статье)

При питании насос пропускает жидкости, но только в заданном направлении.

3) Перевод, предлагаемый автором вопроса

Помпа, подключённая к электросети, будет пропускать жидкость, но только в одном направлении.

4) Редактирование:

**При включении насос будет пропускать (пропускает)  жидкости в направлении, соответствующем его установке.**

Имеется в виду вход-выход, о чём в статье говорилось раньше.

Comment: *это направление задается при его настройке* — а я понимаю так, что задаётся именно при установке; потом уже не перенастроишь. А по Вашему переводу я этого не понял — я бы по этому переводу установил насос, а потом бы искал нужную настройку.

Comment: Перевод технической документации должен быть в первую очередь технически грамотным. Иначе могут возникнуть неприятности при использовании инструкции, переведенной с английского на русский, если английский текст составлялся не очень грамотными китайцами, к примеру.

Comment: Дело в том, что я прочитала в Интернете продолжение текста, где говорится про настройки насоса.  Если я правильно поняла содержание, то   для этого насоса возможна даже такая настройка,  когда направление прокачки жидкости  зависит от определенных условий. Так что это такой особенный насос, и лучше нам здесь не заниматься переводческой работой, да еще одного предложения без контекста.

Comment: Видимо, вы имеете в виду эту статью: https://wiki.factorio.com/Pump  Это предложение следует за заголовком "Использование насоса в качестве управляемого клапана". Это и следующая фраза объясняет оговорку "пропускает, но" (из отдельно взятого предложения можно было предположить, что в выключенном состоянии пропускание двустороннее, поэтому "но" было опущено - верну). В статье ни слова нет о возможности настройки (setup) насоса на противоположное направление, там говорится о входе (source/input) и выходе (output) насоса. _Установлен_ насос может быть _вдоль_ трубы, входом влево или вправо.

Comment: Этой статьи я не видела. После ее прочтения предлагаю редактирование перевода в дополнении к своему ответу на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Смысловой перевод в моём исполнении выглядел бы так:

> *Во время работы помпа перекачивает жидкость со входа на выход.*

-- Ну а дальше пойдёт полемика в виде доказательства *"однонаправленности движения"* этой жидкости. А вариант перевода *"будет пропускать жидкость"* у нас ассоциируется со словами *"соржавела, прохудилась, протекает"*. Кроме того, помпа - *"качает"* эту жидкость, а вот клапаны помпы - те да, те *"пропускают"*.
На последнее обстоятельство (разницу между "качать/пропускать") я бы обратил особое внимание:

- Активное действие - совершать работу с затратой энергии
  "нагнетать, качать, откачивать,".
- Пассивное действие - управлять свершениями
  "разрешить, запретить, пропустить, заблокировать"

Comment: При переводе важен контекст. Этому предложению предшествуют заголовок Use as a Valve (использование в качестве клапана) и подзаголовок The pump works as a controllable valve: (насос работает как управляемый клапан). Содержание этого предложения противопоставляется следующему: If un-powered, the pump doesn't let anything through. (В выключенном состоянии насос ничего не пропускает). Далее говорится о возможности дистанционного переключения между этими состояниями ("пропускания/непропускания") по какому-либо условию. "Помпа" - один из очень немногих видов насоса для откачки из ёмкости (закачки).

Comment: - Верно, @Alex_ander, когда знаешь "предисловие" и "послесловие" - явственно легче догнать смысл изложенного. Если у кого появятся ещё вопросы - буду рад ответить или дополнить свой ответ. А насосов сейчас - жуткое разнообразие, да и принципов их работы - тоже тьма. Вот дорасту до чата - там и подискутирую всласть.   
- Спасибо за комментарий.